# OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 13,223,677,952 bytes (allocated so far: 0 bytes) while performing cupy operation

Tags: python-3.x, cupy

I tried to perform the below cupy operation on a Nvidia GPU :-

import cupy as cp

with cp.cuda.Device(0):

binary_mask = cp.transpose(cp.zeros((img.read_region((0,0),0,img.level_dimensions[0]).size)))

Output :-

OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 13,223,677,952 bytes (allocated so far: 0 bytes)

I am not able to understand why  "allocated so far:0 bytes" is being shown.

If the GPU memory is not getting allocated, how to allocate it for cupy based operations?

Comment: Are you sure you have 12.3 GB of memory?

Comment: No , it is 8GB.
Definitely the memory in the GPU is less than what is required.
I was expecting the GPU to allocate  8589934592 bytes in the error message if I am using 100% of the default memory pool.

Also upon using :- print(cp.get_default_memory_pool().get_limit()) 

the output is 0.